# How to toggle this option PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to toggle this option. When the option is `true`, I want to update it to `false`.

```
update_option('maintenance', true);
```

I've tried the following:

```
if(get_option('maintenance') == true) {
     update_option('maintenance', false);
}

if(get_option('maintenance') == false) {
     update_option('maintenance', true);
}
```

But for some reason this does not work, and is overcomplicated. I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Does anyone got suggestions?

Comment: What's the content of `update_option()` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito When `true`, it'll return 1. If false, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are toggling it twice each time. If it was true, you are updating it to false, then reading it again, finding it to be false, then setting it to true.

Just do it once in a one liner as such (replace all your code):

```
update_option('maintenance', !get_option('maintenance'));
```

This says: Update it to the inverse of what it is right now.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about this trick. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, zed!

Answer (score 0):

What @zed writes is exactly what I'd propose too. But you can use a variable, or even 'normal' `if`s, if you think it's a bit too complex to do it in one line.

With a variable inbetween. This allows you to more easily inspect the variable (for debugging), or to combine multiple values if you would need to.

```
$newvalue = !get_option('maintenance');
update_option('maintenance', $newvalue);
```

Or, if you want to have an if, use `else to prevent the second piece to be executed right away:

```
if(get_option('maintenance') == true) {
     update_option('maintenance', false);
} else {
     update_option('maintenance', true);
}
```

Needless to say that in this particular and simple case, zed's suggestion is the most straightforward.